# Derivation of Gradient Descent Update Rule

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

I am trying to understand the interpretation of Gradient Descent provided in Ryan Tibshirani's 2019 Convex Optimization course scribed notes:

[http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/convexopt-S15/scribes/05-grad-descent-scribed.pdf](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Eryantibs/convexopt-S15/scribes/05-grad-descent-scribed.pdf)

Since they're for me the clearest explanation of the topic I could find.

While I can follow how the function can be approximated at point y as:

$$f(y) ≈ f(x) + ∇f(x)^T (y − x) + \frac{1}{2}(y − x)^T ∇^2f(θ(x − y) + y)(y − x)$$

Which by replacing $∇^2f(θ(x − y) + y)$ with $\frac{1}{t}I$ can be rewritten as:

$$f(y) ≈ f(x) + ∇f(x)^T(y − x) + \frac{1}{2t}||y − x||_2^2 = g(y)$$

I have trouble following the first iff statement given here:

$$∇g(y) = 0 ⇔ ∇f(x)+ \frac{1}{t}(y −x) = 0 ⇔ y = x−t∇f(x)$$

Which, if I understand correctly, derives the GD update rule by first setting its derivative of $g(y)$ to 0, which then results in $∇f(x)+ \frac{1}{t}(y −x)$.

My guess is that the author (like others I have tried to consult, which provide the same reasoning in a slightly different form - see for example slide 19 here: [https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~shais/Lectures2014/lecture6.pdf](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/%7Eshais/Lectures2014/lecture6.pdf), from Shai Shalev-Shwartz's lecture notes, adapted from page 185 of the 2014 book "Understanding Machine Learning:From Theory to Algorithms" by the same author with Shai Ben-David) does not provide a step-by-step explanation of this passage due to its triviality.

But I would nevertheless really appreciate if someone could mathematically break this specific passage down and point to the rules behind it.

Comment: Please provide proper references.  Links can be broken.

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what should I provide? for the second link I could indeed point to the book from the second author, but I don't have an alternative for the first link - that is why I rewrote the equations in the post

Comment: You can still provide the author's name, date, and other context. 10 years from now, if the link is broken, perhaps one can google around and find that PDF file elsewhere.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for the clarification. I'll get to it immediately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$g(y)=f(x) + \nabla f(x)^T(y-x) + \frac1{2t}\|y-x\|_2^2$$

Differentiating with respect to $y$,

$$\nabla g(y) = \nabla f(x) + \frac1{t}(y-x)$$

Hence $$\nabla g(y)=0 \iff \nabla f(x) + \frac1t (y-x)=0$$

which is equivalent to $$\frac1t(y-x) = -\nabla f(x)$$

$$y=x-t\nabla f(x)$$

Note that we have used

$$\nabla_y (a^Ty)=a$$

since $$\frac{\partial }{\partial y_i}\sum_{j=1}^n a_iy_j = a_i$$

and

$$\nabla _y \|y\|^2 = \nabla_y (y^Ty)=2y$$

since $$\frac{\partial }{\partial y_i}\sum_{j=1}^n y_j^2 = 2y_i$$

Comment: Thank you, but my question was how exactly do we get from the first to the second equation in your answer? The remaining passages are clear

Comment: I just edited my post.

Comment: Thanks for the additional clarification, it is now clear how the last term of the first equation changes. but I'm still uncertain on two points: 

1)Does the first term $f(x)$ disappear because it is a constant when taking the derivative with respect to g(y)?

2) Why does the application of the rule $∇_y(a^Ty)=a$ result in $∇f(x)$ and not $f(x)$?

Comment: yes, $f(x)$ is a constant. here $a=\nabla f(x)$.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks again!